# I am not able to integrate mongodb with neo4j

Tags: json, mongodb, neo4j

I wanna integrate mongodb with neo4j so that I can insert json in neo4j. I have done the following steps.

1. Open a terminal and install neo4j-doc-manager (pip install neo4j-doc-manager)
2. Export NEO4J_AUTH=user:password
3. Install mongo-connector
4. rs.initiate() in mongo shell
5. mongod --replSet myDevReplSet  in another mongo shell.
6. mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:7474/db/data -d neo4j_doc_manager
7. db.talks.insert(  { "session": { "title": "12 Years of Spring: An Open Source Journey", "abstract": "Spring emerged as a core open source project in early 2003 and evolved to a broad portfolio of open source projects up until 2015." }, "topics":  ["keynote", "spring"], "room": "Auditorium", "timeslot": "Wed 29th, 09:30-10:30", "speaker": { "name": "Juergen Hoeller", "bio": "Juergen Hoeller is co-founder of the Spring Framework open source project." } } );

But still I am not able to see the graph in neo4j

what did I miss here?

Comment: did you find answer to this problem, as I'm also stuck at this problem